# Xcode 4.1 / 4.2 project compatibility?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, xcode4.2

All:

I have the option to upgrade to Xcode 4.2, but my students, in their computer lab, do not.  Are there any project compatibility issues?  Specifically, can my Xcode 4.2 open an Xcode 4.1 project, and can an Xcode 4.1 project open an Xcode 4.2 project?

Related to this, I see that Xcode 4.2 has quite a few new features (e.g., storyboarding).  If I fire up Xcode in 4.2 in class, but don't use, say, storyboarding, are my students going to see any significant differences?

Thanks much for any insights,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Xcode 4.2 projects can be opened in Xcode 4.1 and vice versa.

In fact, the Xcode file format even in Xcode 4.2 is "Xcode 3.2 compatible". So you can actually open Xcode projects created in Xcode 4.x in Xcode 3.2.x and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

To see the differences between versions, look at what is called the changelog.

http://mac.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Apple-Xcode-Changelog-7935.html

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't mention compatibility AFAICT.